# Analise de ondas sonoras de um arquivo MP3 e representação

Tags: java, android, matemática, áudio

Há alguma forma, em Java/Android de, abrir um arquivo MP3 ou WAV e a partir do mesmo obter as ondas sonoras constantemente ? de acordo com sua reprodução ? e poder a partir desse retorno constante fazer sua representação gráfica ?

Exemplo 1:[image: Vídeo do Canal Tasty]

Vídeo com o objetivo desejado:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bamvg4Icmi0

Comment: Certamente que isso é possível, mas não deve ser algo fácil de se fazer.

Comment: Já estou a algum tempo procurando alguma biblioteca que permita fazer isso, independente da dificuldade que a mesma possa apresentar, o meu projeto necessita dessa funcionalidade, um nome já séria útil mesmo sem exemplos de código

Comment: Acho que alguma coisa daqui vai te mostrar o caminho: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2416935/540552 - Não foque apenas na resposta aceita, algumas das demais respostas foram escritas como crítica ou sugestão de melhoria ou alternativa devido a alguns problemas na resposta aceita.

Comment: Eu tenho uma lib no github, depois se quiser dar uma olhada: https://github.com/cleidimarviana/equalizers porém as barras se movem não de acordo com o som. Basicamente ´´e uma simulação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já tem uma resposta e vários comentários, dei uma rápida olhada nas bibliotecas que foram propostas só de curiosidade, mas infelizmente nenhuma delas realmente faz o que você parece precisar :-(

Não procure por `equalizer` um equalizador tem a função de atenuar ou dar enfase em uma frequência específica ou em um conjunto delas (banda de frequência), você está procurando um `Audio spectrum Analyzer` cada frame de áudio processado é analisado pela [Transformada de fourier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_de_Fourier) essa é a mágica.

Eu não conheço bibliotecas prontas em java, eu só sei como fazer, talvez explicando você consiga entender os passos necessários.

- Você vai precisar decodificar seu áudio mp3, esse processo permite  representar digitalmente sinais analógicos amostrados, isso quer dizer que você terá o áudio de forma pura, você vai ter todos os valores da amplitude do sinal amostrado em um determinado intervalo.
- De modo concorrente você analisa cada pedaço de áudio enquanto ele também toca, geralmente é utilizado pedaços de tamanho com potência de dois, isso simplifica e dá ganho de desempenho junto a transformada de fourier, não quero entrar na matemática profunda, a grosso modo a transformada de fourier decompõe um sinal em componentes espectrais (frequências).
- Com a representação das frequências de cada amostra você deve plotar ou desenhar os valores para conseguir o efeito que deseja.

Há muito tempo atrás eu fiz esse [algoritmo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw6jbAbvsvo) em python para testar, na realidade tem alguns detalhes sobre o quão preciso você quer que o efeito seja, quanto maior a janela passada para fourier menor será a ordem de resolução dos componentes espectrais, mas é claro isso tem um custo computacional e você vai precisar decidir um tamanho de janela que seja o melhor custo benefício para o seu app.

O exemplo que você mostrou só de olhar o gráfico dá pra perceber que ele funciona muito bem com as frequências baixas, mas quase não tem interação com os agudos, repara no minuto [2:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyWjKQo9-m8), começa uma voz e o analisador de espectro quase não tem mudanças, isso me diz que o algoritmo só esta demonstrando faixas de frequências mais graves...

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas bibliotecas que podem fazer isso por você: [MiniEqualizer](https://github.com/claucookie/mini-equalizer-library-android) e [VuMeter](https://github.com/HugoGresse/AndroidVuMeter/blob/master/vumeterlibrary/src/main/java/io/gresse/hugo/vumeterlibrary/Dynamics.java).

Elas possuem o mesmo efeito e se você for olhar o código fonte delas, vai ver que elas herdam de uma `View`, o que dá a você a possibilidade de editar e fazer algo semelhante ao do vídeo.

No caso, você teria que sincronizar a `View` com o seu `Player`.

**Outras alternativas**: [WaveInApp](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3493), [Horizon](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3329)

Comment: Valeu Luc, obrigado